# JFrame resizable height ONLY

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, resizable

`JFrame.setResizable(true)` lets the user resize both the width and height of a window. Does a method exist which allows the user to ONLY resize the height?

Thanks.

**Edit:** The solutions below do NOT seem to work. On a 360x600 JFrame,

```
setResizable(true);
pack();
setMaximizedBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 360, 1200));
setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(360, 1200));
setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(360, 600));
setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(360, 600));
setVisible(true);
```

Still allows fully stretching the width of the JFrame, and setting `setResizable(false)` allows nothing to be stretched.

Comment: Did you find a solution afterwards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below does the job right.

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        setSize(new Dimension(preferredWidth, getHeight()));
        super.componentResized(e);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! That works and as I am mostly concerned with keeping a minimum width, 
                `if (getWidth() < preferredWidth)
                {
                    setSize(new Dimension(preferredWidth, getHeight()));
                }` works great.

Comment: @brian_d I was actually looking for a solution for the same problem. And was really disappointed to find out that your question doesn't have the solution I was looking for. Anyway, I found the solution somewhere else on the internet and it worked.

Comment: This works pretty well except that it does not prevent the user from maximizing the window

Comment: @Bao-LongNguyen-Trong you can disable maximization quit easily though

Comment: infact setResizable(false) did the trick for me. It even disabled maximization (dimmed the icon)

Comment: @DheeB We needed fixed height instead of fixed size.

Comment: Unfortunately when you're fighting with the layoutmanager like this, it leads to an ugly permanent flickering inside your gui, which was pretty dealbreaking for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have experience with JNI, then this is a possible solution.

In Windows and Oracle Hotspot, this code will allow a window to be resized between minimum and maximum dimensions without flickering or causing any of the nasty JFrame-post-resize side-effects.  If this code is called once the JFrame is created and made visible, then the code used above in componentResized() to catch resize events can be completely done away with, as Windows has facilities to keep the user from being able to resize above or below the specified min/max sizes.

// Java code:

```
static {
    if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("32"))
    {   // 32-bit JVM
        System.loadLibrary("my32bitdll");
        System.out.println("Running 32-bit JVM");

    } else {
        // 64-bit JVM
        System.loadLibrary("my64bitdll");
        System.out.println("Running 64-bit JVM");
    }
}
// Sets a window to never be resized above or below these minimum widths/heights
public static native int setMinMaxResizeBoundaries(int hwnd, int minWidth, int minHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight);
```

// C++ code (include standard windows.h, winbase.h, etc)

```
// Global variables defined in DllMain.cpp
// Used for setMinMaxResizeBoundaries()
struct SHwndMinMax
{
    HWND    hwnd;
    int     minWidth;
    int     minHeight;
    int     maxWidth;
    int     maxHeight;
    WNDPROC prefWndProc;
};
SHwndMinMax gsHwndMinMax[2048];
int gsHwndMinMaxCount = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK MinMaxWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// Code added somwhere:
// setMinMaxResizeBoundaries()
// Sets the resize boundary window sizes, so the window will not be resized above/below that size
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_your_class_here_setMinMaxResizeBoundaries(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls,
    jint hwnd,
    jint minWidth, jint minHeight,
    jint maxWidth, jint maxHeight)
{
    // We create a hook for the window, and intercept the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message occurs, and update the info
    if (IsWindow((HWND)hwnd))
    {   // Let's add it
        if (gsHwndMinMaxCount < 2048)
        {   // We're good
            // Can add code here to check if this option is valid or not--so it can later be "unhooked" by a separate function call
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].hwnd        = (HWND)hwnd;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].minWidth    = minWidth;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].minHeight   = minHeight;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].maxWidth    = maxWidth;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].maxHeight   = maxHeight;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].prefWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&MinMaxWindowProc);
            // Success
            ++gsHwndMinMaxCount;
            return(0);

        } else {
            // Failuire, too many hooks
            return(-2);
        }

    } else {
        // Failure, HWND is not valid
        return(-1);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MinMaxWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int i;
    MINMAXINFO* mmi;

    for (i = 0; i < gsHwndMinMaxCount; i++)
    {
        if (hwnd == gsHwndMinMax[i].hwnd)
        {   // This is our man, see if it's our message
            if (msg == WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
            {   // It is
                // When maximized, window is at upper-left
                mmi = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam;
                mmi->ptMaxSize.x        = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxWidth;
                mmi->ptMaxSize.y        = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxHeight;
                mmi->ptMaxPosition.x    = 0;  // Can add code here to properly position the window centered in the screen, etc.
                mmi->ptMaxPosition.y    = 0;  // Same here
                // Set the minimum and maximum tracking size (when the user is resizing, what's the smallest and biggest window they see)
                mmi->ptMinTrackSize.x   = gsHwndMinMax[i].minWidth;
                mmi->ptMinTrackSize.y   = gsHwndMinMax[i].minHeight;
                mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.x   = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxWidth;
                mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.y   = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxHeight;
                return(DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));

            } else {
                // Nope, pass it on
                return(CallWindowProc(gsHwndMinMax[i].prefWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

// The following is code to get the HWND accurately:

// Java Code (add to Java code above)

```
// Returns the HWND for the specified component, or -1 if does not exist
public static native int getComponentHWND(Component c);
```

// Code in C++

```
// getComponentHWND()
// Called to return the HWND of the component, if it has one.
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_your_class_here_getComponentHWND(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject obj)
{
    HWND hWnd = 0;
    typedef jboolean (JNICALL *PJAWT_GETAWT)(JNIEnv*, JAWT*);
    JAWT awt;
    JAWT_DrawingSurface* ds;
    JAWT_DrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi;
    JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi_win;
    jboolean result;
    jint lock;
    HMODULE _hAWT = 0;

    // Load AWT Library
    if (!_hAWT)
        _hAWT = LoadLibrary(L"jawt.dll");   // for Java 1.4+

    if (!_hAWT)
        _hAWT = LoadLibrary(L"awt.dll");    // for Java 1.3

    if (_hAWT)
    {
        PJAWT_GETAWT JAWT_GetAWT = (PJAWT_GETAWT)GetProcAddress(_hAWT, "JAWT_GetAWT");
        if (JAWT_GetAWT)
        {
            awt.version = JAWT_VERSION_1_4;     // Init here with JAWT_VERSION_1_3 or JAWT_VERSION_1_4
            // Get AWT API Interface
            result = JAWT_GetAWT(env, &awt);
            if (result != JNI_FALSE)
            {
                ds = awt.GetDrawingSurface(env, obj);
                if (ds != NULL)
                {
                    lock = ds->Lock(ds);
                    if ((lock & JAWT_LOCK_ERROR) == 0)
                    {
                        dsi = ds->GetDrawingSurfaceInfo(ds);
                        if (dsi)
                        {
                            dsi_win = (JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo*)dsi->platformInfo;
                            if (dsi_win)
                                hWnd = dsi_win->hwnd;
                            else
                                hWnd = (HWND) -1;   // Failed to obtain the handle (not running on Windows)

                            ds->FreeDrawingSurfaceInfo(dsi);

                        } else {
                            hWnd = (HWND)-2;    // Failed to get the drawing surface info block
                        }
                        ds->Unlock(ds);

                    } else {
                        hWnd = (HWND)-3;    // Failed to lock the drawing surface to obtain information about it
                    }
                    awt.FreeDrawingSurface(ds);

                } else {
                    hWnd = (HWND)-4;    // Failed to get the drawing surface from the compoment
                }
            } else {
                hWnd = (HWND)-5;    // Failed to obtain a proper result from _JAWT_GetAWT()
            }
        } else {
            hWnd = (HWND)-6;    // Failed to find "_JAWT_GetAWT()" function
        }
    } else {
        hWnd = (HWND)-7;    // Failed to load awt.dll
    }
    return (jint)hWnd;
}
```

Comment: Note:  This solution **does** work correctly with Windows and Java 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: Oh Lord.... please forgive him. You may offer a pray to no one change these library names .... I'll note this as a very good example of coupling. I dare say your machine and your code are MARRIED forever!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a method expressly for that purpose. However, you could preset the JFrame's preferred, minimum, and maximum size such that the widths are all equal.

```
Dimension dimPreferred = frame.getPreferedSize();
Dimension dimMinimum = frame.getMinimumSize();
Dimension dimMaximum = frame.getMaximumSize();
dimPreferred.setWidth( FIXED_WIDTH );
dimMinimum.setWidth( FIXED_WIDTH );
dimMaximum.setWidth( FIXED_WIDTH );
frame.setPreferredSize( dimPreferred );
frame.setMinimumSize( dimMinimum );
frame.setMaximumSize( dimMaximum );
```

You will probably want to do this *after* `frame.pack()` and *before* `frame.setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe most platforms will honour `setMaximumSize` and `setMinimumSize`. There is also `setMaximizedBounds`.

What doesn't work is adding a listener to reset the width. Threading issues makes it look unpleasant. If you have PL&F decorated windows (not supported by the Windows PL&F), then they can be hacked about with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setResizable(true)` use `setResizable(false)`
Infact setResizable(false) did the trick for me. **It even disabled maximization (dimmed the icon)**

> Okay, I should have explained myself better. I wanted to get the resizeable thing working too. That's why I landed on this question. But I finally went with this, thought that would help the OP.
>
> I wanted to do resizable too, but thought if I can't get resizable to work, disabling is better because it won't mess up your content placement. Thought I'd suggest that as a solution.

Comment: How will that make the height resizeable?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström it doesn't. It helped me lay my components. Thought that would help the OP.

Comment: @htz Okay, I should have explained myself better. I wanted to get the resizeable thing working too. That's why I landed on this question. But I finally went with this, thought that would help the OP.

Comment: But how is it an answer to this question? @DheerajBhaskar

Comment: I wanted to do resizable too, but thought if I can't get resizable to work, disabling is better because it won't mess up your content placement. Thought I'd suggest that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid flickering, you can override #setBounds method in your JFrame. Seems like every resize will call it. Something like

```
@Override
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    if (width == FIXED_WIDTH) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code exactly for this purpose and it works (it is actually **edited @Hoazhun solution** as his original code will lock both width and height, but in my version you can set height manually yet having width fixed):

```html
int defWindowW = 300;
int defWindowH = 600;
JFrame MAIN_WINDOW = new JFrame();

MAIN_WINDOW.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {

        int W = Integer.parseInt(e.paramString().split(",")[1].split(" ")[1].split("x")[0].replace(")", ""));
        int H = Integer.parseInt(e.paramString().split(",")[1].split(" ")[1].split("x")[1].replace(")", ""));

        /* FOR FIXED WIDTH - ACTIVE NOW, COMMENT IT OUT FOR DISABLING*/ MAIN_WINDOW.setSize(new Dimension(defWindowW, H));
        
        /* FOR FIXED HEIGHT - UNCOMMENT TO MAKE IT ACTIVE */
        //MAIN_WINDOW.setSize(new Dimension(W, defWindowH));

        super.componentResized(e);
    }
});
```