# JFrame - allow vertical but not horizontal resizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize

I've written a Java desktop application which is running on OS X and Windows.

I using Java and `JFrame` as a window frame and I want allow to resize this window only in vertical way.

I know that there is `frame.setResizable(false)` but it blocks resizing in both ways.

I used:

```
frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 1000));
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
```

That means I declare max frame size in `horizontal = 300` and `vertical = 1000` and min frame size `horizontal = 300` and `vertical = 500` and on OS X it works (can resize in vertical from 500 to 1000, horizontal is blocked), but on Windows it doe **not** work (allow to resize in both ways).

I try also `addComponentListener` but it makes frame stretch then snap back, it looks ugly.

How to block horizontal resizing and allow only vertical resizing?

Somebody have similar problem?

**Any idea to resolve it?**

Comment: *"..it looks ugly."* An app. that resizes one direction but not another is ***not*** the 'path of least surprise' for the end user! Why not just pad either side of the main component when there is more space than needed? The user will get the idea..

Comment: There is no option to block this so I am forced to do resizable in both ways :/ Maybe somebody resolve this problem anyway... ?

Comment: *"Maybe somebody resolve this problem"* The way I see it, you are trying to make a problem (for the user) rather than fix one. *"I am forced to do resizable in both ways :/"* There, there. There, there..

Comment: Maybe this topic helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663174/jframe-resizable-height-only

Comment: `I try also addComponentListener but it makes frame stretch then snap back,` - there is no default support for this. I also see no reason for this requirement. Let me as a user determine how I want to use the space on my desktop. If I want to change the width who cares?