# JNI - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file

Tags: java, c++, batch-file, compiler-errors, java-native-interface

Based on the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287438/4601149) I tried to make an example of it before I implemented it into my actual program. However, I get the following error:

```
c:\users\danie\dropbox\programming\code\notepad++\java\stack overflow\questions\jnitest\JNI.h(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jni.h': No such file or directory.
```

I believe it is to do with the second line of the header file, however, that is automatically generated so I am not sure. Here are the source files.

**JNI.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JNI extends JFrame {

    /**
    * This should only allow resize in one direction with no glitches
    */

    private JNI() {
        super("JNI Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setMaximizedBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 360, 1200));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(360, 1200));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(360, 600));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(360, 600));
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JNI();
    }

    static {
        if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("32")) {// 32-bit JVM
            System.loadLibrary("my32bitdll");
            System.out.println("Running 32-bit JVM");
        } else { // 64-bit JVM
            System.loadLibrary("my64bitdll");
            System.out.println("Running 64-bit JVM");
        }
    }
    // Sets a window to never be resized above or below these minimum widths/heights
    public static native int setMinMaxResizeBoundaries(int hwnd, int minWidth, int minHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight);
    public static native int getComponentHWND(Component c);
}
```

**DllMain.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include "JNI.h"

// Global variables defined in DllMain.cpp
// Used for setMinMaxResizeBoundaries()
struct SHwndMinMax
{
    HWND    hwnd;
    int     minWidth;
    int     minHeight;
    int     maxWidth;
    int     maxHeight;
    WNDPROC prefWndProc;
};
SHwndMinMax gsHwndMinMax[2048];
int gsHwndMinMaxCount = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK MinMaxWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// Code added somwhere:
// setMinMaxResizeBoundaries()
// Sets the resize boundary window sizes, so the window will not be resized above/below that size
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNI_setMinMaxResizeBoundaries(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls,
    jint hwnd,
    jint minWidth, jint minHeight,
    jint maxWidth, jint maxHeight)
{
    // We create a hook for the window, and intercept the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message occurs, and update the info
    if (IsWindow((HWND)hwnd))
    {   // Let's add it
        if (gsHwndMinMaxCount < 2048)
        {   // We're good
            // Can add code here to check if this option is valid or not--so it can later be "unhooked" by a separate function call
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].hwnd        = (HWND)hwnd;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].minWidth    = minWidth;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].minHeight   = minHeight;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].maxWidth    = maxWidth;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].maxHeight   = maxHeight;
            gsHwndMinMax[gsHwndMinMaxCount].prefWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&MinMaxWindowProc);
            // Success
            ++gsHwndMinMaxCount;
            return(0);

        } else {
            // Failuire, too many hooks
            return(-2);
        }

    } else {
        // Failure, HWND is not valid
        return(-1);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MinMaxWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int i;
    MINMAXINFO* mmi;

    for (i = 0; i < gsHwndMinMaxCount; i++)
    {
        if (hwnd == gsHwndMinMax[i].hwnd)
        {   // This is our man, see if it's our message
            if (msg == WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
            {   // It is
                // When maximized, window is at upper-left
                mmi = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam;
                mmi->ptMaxSize.x        = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxWidth;
                mmi->ptMaxSize.y        = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxHeight;
                mmi->ptMaxPosition.x    = 0;  // Can add code here to properly position the window centered in the screen, etc.
                mmi->ptMaxPosition.y    = 0;  // Same here
                // Set the minimum and maximum tracking size (when the user is resizing, what's the smallest and biggest window they see)
                mmi->ptMinTrackSize.x   = gsHwndMinMax[i].minWidth;
                mmi->ptMinTrackSize.y   = gsHwndMinMax[i].minHeight;
                mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.x   = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxWidth;
                mmi->ptMaxTrackSize.y   = gsHwndMinMax[i].maxHeight;
                return(DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));

            } else {
                // Nope, pass it on
                return(CallWindowProc(gsHwndMinMax[i].prefWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

// getComponentHWND()
// Called to return the HWND of the component, if it has one.
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNI_getComponentHWND(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject obj)
{
    HWND hWnd = 0;
    typedef jboolean (JNICALL *PJAWT_GETAWT)(JNIEnv*, JAWT*);
    JAWT awt;
    JAWT_DrawingSurface* ds;
    JAWT_DrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi;
    JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo* dsi_win;
    jboolean result;
    jint lock;
    HMODULE _hAWT = 0;

    // Load AWT Library
    if (!_hAWT)
        _hAWT = LoadLibrary(L"jawt.dll");   // for Java 1.4+

    if (!_hAWT)
        _hAWT = LoadLibrary(L"awt.dll");    // for Java 1.3

    if (_hAWT)
    {
        PJAWT_GETAWT JAWT_GetAWT = (PJAWT_GETAWT)GetProcAddress(_hAWT, "JAWT_GetAWT");
        if (JAWT_GetAWT)
        {
            awt.version = JAWT_VERSION_1_4;     // Init here with JAWT_VERSION_1_3 or JAWT_VERSION_1_4
            // Get AWT API Interface
            result = JAWT_GetAWT(env, &awt);
            if (result != JNI_FALSE)
            {
                ds = awt.GetDrawingSurface(env, obj);
                if (ds != NULL)
                {
                    lock = ds->Lock(ds);
                    if ((lock & JAWT_LOCK_ERROR) == 0)
                    {
                        dsi = ds->GetDrawingSurfaceInfo(ds);
                        if (dsi)
                        {
                            dsi_win = (JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo*)dsi->platformInfo;
                            if (dsi_win)
                                hWnd = dsi_win->hwnd;
                            else
                                hWnd = (HWND) -1;   // Failed to obtain the handle (not running on Windows)

                            ds->FreeDrawingSurfaceInfo(dsi);

                        } else {
                            hWnd = (HWND)-2;    // Failed to get the drawing surface info block
                        }
                        ds->Unlock(ds);

                    } else {
                        hWnd = (HWND)-3;    // Failed to lock the drawing surface to obtain information about it
                    }
                    awt.FreeDrawingSurface(ds);

                } else {
                    hWnd = (HWND)-4;    // Failed to get the drawing surface from the compoment
                }
            } else {
                hWnd = (HWND)-5;    // Failed to obtain a proper result from _JAWT_GetAWT()
            }
        } else {
            hWnd = (HWND)-6;    // Failed to find "_JAWT_GetAWT()" function
        }
    } else {
        hWnd = (HWND)-7;    // Failed to load awt.dll
    }
    return (jint)hWnd;
}
```

**JNI.h** - *Generated with batch file*

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class JNI */

#ifndef _Included_JNI
#define _Included_JNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef JNI_FOCUS_TRAVERSABLE_UNKNOWN
#define JNI_FOCUS_TRAVERSABLE_UNKNOWN 0L
#undef JNI_FOCUS_TRAVERSABLE_DEFAULT
#define JNI_FOCUS_TRAVERSABLE_DEFAULT 1L
#undef JNI_FOCUS_TRAVERSABLE_SET
#define JNI_FOCUS_TRAVERSABLE_SET 2L
#undef JNI_TOP_ALIGNMENT
#define JNI_TOP_ALIGNMENT 0.0f
#undef JNI_CENTER_ALIGNMENT
#define JNI_CENTER_ALIGNMENT 0.5f
#undef JNI_BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT
#define JNI_BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT 1.0f
#undef JNI_LEFT_ALIGNMENT
#define JNI_LEFT_ALIGNMENT 0.0f
#undef JNI_RIGHT_ALIGNMENT
#define JNI_RIGHT_ALIGNMENT 1.0f
#undef JNI_serialVersionUID
#define JNI_serialVersionUID -7644114512714619750i64
#undef JNI_serialVersionUID
#define JNI_serialVersionUID 4613797578919906343i64
#undef JNI_INCLUDE_SELF
#define JNI_INCLUDE_SELF 1L
#undef JNI_SEARCH_HEAVYWEIGHTS
#define JNI_SEARCH_HEAVYWEIGHTS 1L
#undef JNI_OPENED
#define JNI_OPENED 1L
#undef JNI_serialVersionUID
#define JNI_serialVersionUID 4497834738069338734i64
#undef JNI_DEFAULT_CURSOR
#define JNI_DEFAULT_CURSOR 0L
#undef JNI_CROSSHAIR_CURSOR
#define JNI_CROSSHAIR_CURSOR 1L
#undef JNI_TEXT_CURSOR
#define JNI_TEXT_CURSOR 2L
#undef JNI_WAIT_CURSOR
#define JNI_WAIT_CURSOR 3L
#undef JNI_SW_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_SW_RESIZE_CURSOR 4L
#undef JNI_SE_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_SE_RESIZE_CURSOR 5L
#undef JNI_NW_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_NW_RESIZE_CURSOR 6L
#undef JNI_NE_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_NE_RESIZE_CURSOR 7L
#undef JNI_N_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_N_RESIZE_CURSOR 8L
#undef JNI_S_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_S_RESIZE_CURSOR 9L
#undef JNI_W_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_W_RESIZE_CURSOR 10L
#undef JNI_E_RESIZE_CURSOR
#define JNI_E_RESIZE_CURSOR 11L
#undef JNI_HAND_CURSOR
#define JNI_HAND_CURSOR 12L
#undef JNI_MOVE_CURSOR
#define JNI_MOVE_CURSOR 13L
#undef JNI_NORMAL
#define JNI_NORMAL 0L
#undef JNI_ICONIFIED
#define JNI_ICONIFIED 1L
#undef JNI_MAXIMIZED_HORIZ
#define JNI_MAXIMIZED_HORIZ 2L
#undef JNI_MAXIMIZED_VERT
#define JNI_MAXIMIZED_VERT 4L
#undef JNI_MAXIMIZED_BOTH
#define JNI_MAXIMIZED_BOTH 6L
#undef JNI_serialVersionUID
#define JNI_serialVersionUID 2673458971256075116i64
#undef JNI_EXIT_ON_CLOSE
#define JNI_EXIT_ON_CLOSE 3L
/*
 * Class:     JNI
 * Method:    setMinMaxResizeBoundaries
 * Signature: (IIIII)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNI_setMinMaxResizeBoundaries
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint, jint, jint, jint);

/*
 * Class:     JNI
 * Method:    getComponentHWND
 * Signature: (Ljava/awt/Component;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNI_getComponentHWND
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**Batch File**

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
javac JNI.java
javah -jni JNI
cl /EHsc DllMain.cpp
pause
```

Also, all my files are in the same directory

[image: Directory with files in]

I would appreciate any help in solving this problem.

---

Also if anyone can tell me why my console output looks like this when the batch file runs

[image: Looks]

Instead of this

[image: Should look like]

I would appreciate it

---

**Edit**
Working batch file.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
javac JNI.java
javah -jni JNI
cl -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/include/win32" -MD -LD DllMain.cpp -FeDllMain.dll
pause
```

*Note this still doesn't show steps if anyone has an answer for that*

Comment: `jni.h` should be located in the `include` directory of your JDK installation. Have you added that directory to the include-directories in your project settings?

Comment: @Michael I am writing in Notepadd+ so I am not sure how I would do that

Comment: @Michael How should I change it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx   Look for something involving adding additional include directories.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I will look into that

Comment: @Michael I updated my batch however I still get the same error? Any ideas? Also is it to do with the `include` line in **`JNI.h`**

Comment: @Michael I fixed the problem. See edit if you wish